# Unexpected integer math results on Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to smoothly transition an RGB LED from one colour to another. As part of the logic for this I have the following function to determine how big the change will be (it multiplies by a factor `f` to avoid floating-point math):

```
int colorDelta(int from, int to, int f) {
  int delta;

  if (to == from) {
    delta = 0;
  } else {
    delta = (to - from) * f;
  }

  return delta;
}
```

**When I call `colorDelta(0, 255, 1000)` I expect the result to be `-255000` but instead the function returns `7144`.**

I've tried performing the operation as directly as possible for debugging, but `Serial.print((0 - 255) * 1000, DEC);` also writes `7144` to the serial port.

What have I foolishly overlooked here? I'd really like to see the (smoothly transitioning) light. ;)

Comment: Looks like you have overlooked `sizeof(int)` being less than you expect, like 2 (there's no room for -255000 in 16 bits)

Comment: You're absolutely right; changing to `f=100` or using `long` instead of `int` works as expected. Write this up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect an integer overflow: the `int` type being incapable of holding -255000. By language standard, signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, but in practice the major bits of a result are *usually* just thrown away (warning: this observation is not meant to be used in *writing code*, because undefined behavior remains undefined; it's just for those cases when you have to *reason* about the program that is known to be wrong).

A good way to check it quickly is computing a difference between your real result and your expected one: `-255000 - 7144 = -262144`. The latter is `-(1<<18)`, which is the indication that my suspicions are well-founded.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I changed my function to return a `long` and changed the else clause to `delta = ((long)to - from) * f;` and everything works as expected. This silly mistake tells me it's time for bed!